# How to install h5py for python 3.6 on windows without Microsoft Visual c++ 14.0

Tags: python, pip, hdf5, h5py

The [python package index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py) only has versions for python 2.4 to 2.7, as does the wheels on [Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#h5py). After installing cython from a wheel,

`pip install h5py`

gives the error: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required."

How can I install h5py for python 3.6 without Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0?

Comment: I don't think you can, but visual c++ 14 is free. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listed versions on PyPI are versions of the h5py library, not prebuilt wheels for a version of CPython. If you need h5py for CPython 3.6, there is a suite of `h5py-2.7.0rc2-cp36*.whl` packages @ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py/2.7.0rc2 . Pick your architecture and you should be all set.